# How can I view Java's cache?

Tags: java, cache

If I use `Control Panel > Java > View temporary files`, I can view cached `.class` files, `.gif` files, etc. Why can't I see them in `/../Application Data/Sun/../cache`?

Answer (score 0):

On my system there's a **`6.0`** subfolder under `Sun/Java/Deployment/cache` with many subfolders, namely `0` to whatever positive integer (`63` for me - mabe there are always exactly 64) as well as `host`, `muffin` (cookies...?), `splash` and `tmp`. Also there are two files `lastAccessed` and `removed.apps`.

Some folders do have contents, but most of the files you will find do not have an extension. If you open them in a hex editor you can probably guess what their types are. I found some jars (that are actually zips) and gifs and even class files (watch out for a pretty girl called `CAFE BABE`).